# Find the probabilities for the various configurations of the birthdays of $30$ people born in a leap year?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

Find the probabilities for the various configurations of the birthdays of $30$ people born in a leap year.

My guess is that total configurations are $\binom{366}{30}$. Is that right? 
These are for choosing the days, assigning them to the $30$ people can be done in different ways or will that be taken care by the combination itself?

Comment: Can people have the same birthday ? In this case, we have $366^{30}$ possible configurations.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  What you have calculated is the number of ways each person could have a different birthday.  Since there are $366^{30}$ possible distributions of birthdays, figuring out each probability could take quite some time.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What does "configuration" mean in the context of this problem?  Can you give an example or 2, so we can be sure what you mean?

Comment: $\binom{366}{30}$ only works under the extra conditions that on every day *at most one* of $30$ celebrates his/her birthday.

Comment: @Peter, Yes they can have same birthdays.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you!, I'll learn how to typeset mathematics, in here.
Thank you! for editing the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the persons are distinguishable by their identity then - as commented - there are $366^{30}$ configurations.

If the persons are only distinguishable by their birthdays then you must find the number of tuples: $$\langle a_1,\cdots,a_{366}\rangle\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}^{366}$$ that satisfy:$$\sum_{i=1}^{366}a_i=30$$

Here $a_i$ corresponds with the number of birthdays on day $i$.

This can be done with application of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and gives outcome $$\binom{30+366-1}{366-1}$$